# Understanding the mathematical proof for the alias frequencies in a sampled sine wave

Tags: sampling, aliasing, proof

I'm struggling to get my head round the mathematical proof for the alias frequencies in a sampled sine wave.

I understand that sampling a sine wave of frequency $f_0$ every $t_s$ seconds gives you:

$$x[n]=\sin(2\pi f_0nt_s)$$

I also understand that, because the sine wave is periodic every $2\pi$, you can add any multiple of $2\pi$ to the angle and get the same values for the sine, i.e.,

$$\sin(2\pi f_0nt_s)=\sin(2\pi f_0nt_s+2\pi m) \quad\text{(where $m$ is any integer).}$$

The proof I'm looking at then factors out $2\pi$ and $nt_s$ to get:

$$\sin\left(2\pi(f_0+\frac{m}{nt_s})nt_s\right)$$

...but then it says to let $m$ be an integer multiple of $n$ so we can replace the $\frac{m}{n}$ ratio with an integer $k$.

I don't understand how $m$ can go from being *"any integer"* to *"an integer multiple of $n$"*. If $m$ is any integer and $n$ is an integer then how can the ratio between them be an integer?

I know I'm missing something obvious here and I'm searching for that light-bulb moment but it's not happening. Because this is so fundamental to DSP I don't just want to accept the formula and move on without thoroughly understanding it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the whole proof?

Comment: @oxuf I don't have a link, I'm afraid. It's in a book "Understanding Digital Signal Processing by Richard G. Lyons".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that if it is true for *any $m$*, it is also true for $m=kn$.

I will sketch the proof in another way.

Call $f_s = 1/t_s$ sampling frequency where $t_s$ is sampling period, the two signal $x(t) = \sin(2\pi f_0 t)$ and $x_k(t) = \sin(2\pi (f_0 + k f_s) t)$ have the same values at sampling instants (aliasing), i.e. $x[n] = x_k[n]$.

Indeed,

\begin{align}
x[n] &= \sin (2 \pi f_0 n t_s) \\
x_k[n] &= \sin \left(2 \pi (f_0 + k f_s) n t_s\right) \\
&= \sin (2 \pi f_0 n t_s + 2\pi k f_s n t_s) \\
&= \sin (2 \pi f_0 n t_s + 2\pi k n) = \sin (2 \pi f_0 n t_s)\\
&=x[n]
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can see that if you work backwards you can show that for every value of k you get an alias frequency, but does that mean there might be other values of m that we've ignored that might also produce an alias frequency? Sorry - I'm sure I'm missing something quite fundamental and obvious. Maybe I just need to keep experimenting by plugging different values in the formulas and see which ones do/don't create alias frequencies.

Comment: Try changing $k f_s$ by an arbitrary $\Delta f$ and calculate the substraction $x[n] - x_{\Delta f}[n]$. To have alias, the substraction needs to be equal to 0 for **all** $n$ then $\Delta f$ must be a multiple of $1/t_s$.

Comment: Thanks @AlexTP that's a useful way to look at it. It also helped me see what the mathematical proof was getting at as well. If $\Delta f=\frac{m}{nts}=\frac{m}{n}f_s$ then $m=n\frac{\Delta f}{f_s}$ and the only way for $m$ to be an integer for all $n$ is if $\frac{\Delta f}{f_s}$ is also an integer, $k$. $\frac{\Delta f}{f_s}=k$ so $\Delta f=kf_s$

Comment: @AlexTP: your answer was great but is it independent of the nyquist frequency. you didn't mention nyquist so my guess is yes. thanks.

Comment: @markleeds it's my understanding (which admittedly is still very limited) that this formula kind of leads you to the Nyquist frequency. It's showing that, when sampling, you'll get spectral replications in the frequency domain every $f_s$, so then you need to choose a value for the sampling rate $f_s$ such that the replications won't interfere with other giving aliasing errors in your band of interest.

Comment: @IanR you got it.

Comment: Great explanations from both of you. All the best.

Comment: @AlexTP: If you don't mind, could you tell me if the following understanding is correct. Assume that $f_{0}$ is the highest frequency one wants to detect in the signal. Then, if $f_{s} <  f_{0}/2 $, there will be no aliasing that occurs for any frequencies between $0$ and $f_{0}$. If this is correct, then I need to think about this statement more but atleast I know that I'm on the right track. Thanks. IanR I would have addressed you also but it only allows one.

Comment: @markleeds No, if your sinusoid are in $[0, f_0]$ will be replicated to $[f_s,f_0+f_s]$. Thus to avoid aliasing, $f_0 < f_s$. For baseband equivalent signal, its spectrum is non-zero in $[-f_0, f_0]$ that is copied to $[-f_0 + f_s,f_0+f_s]$ and Nyquist said that to avoid aliasing $f_0 < -f_0 + f_s$, or $f_s > 2f_0$. This figure visualizes the statement https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/AliasedSpectrum.png/400px-AliasedSpectrum.png

Comment: @AlexTP: Thanks. Will print out and combine with my other notes on aliasing and check out the link.  Hopefully eventual understanding will happen.. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why the originally referenced proof feels unintuitive and unsatisfying is that upon first read it appears they are selecting any old integer that may satisfy the proof (the integer multiple of $n$ really bothered me when I first looked at). In actuality, however, they are selecting the *exact* and only integers that satisfy the proof for a given $k$ in $\sin(2 \pi (f_0 + f_s k)n / f_s)$. For each sample, the $f_0 + f_sk$ frequency goes through exactly $nk$ cycles more than $f_0$ does, and so reaches the same value at the sample.

In my opinion, graphing this really helps, so let's consider a situation where we are sampling $32$ times a second and start with a base frequency of $4$Hz. Taking $k=1$, we can graph frequency $f_0=4$ and $f_1=4 + 32 \cdot 1$, and mark the sample points:
[image]

Taking a look at the first two non-zero samples, you can see that $f_1 = 4 + 32\cdot 1$ goes though exactly $1$ and $2$ more cycles than $f_0$ respectively. This makes sense because $k=1$ and for the first sample $n=1$ and for the second $n=2$.

Next $f_0=4$ and $f_2=4 + 32 \cdot 2$:
[image]

Now $k=2$, and we see for $n=1$, $f_2= 4+32 \cdot 2$ goes through $2$ extra cycles for $n=1$ and $4$ extra cycles for $n=2$, and so on, all equal to $nk$. This is true for any integer $n$ and any integer $k$.

Key:

[image]